# > Could not find com.android.support:design:30.0.3

Tags: android

am a beginner and encountered me this problem, implementation
DESIGN NOT WORK

and this my code

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mytest"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:30.0.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

}

Comment: `com.android.support:design` is deprecated and last version of it is `28.0.0`. See answer for artifact that superseded it.

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:30.0.3'
```

> Note: With the release of Android 9.0 (API level 28) there is a new version of the support library called AndroidX which is part of Jetpack. The AndroidX library contains the existing support library and also includes the latest Jetpack components.

You can continue to use the support library. Historical artifacts (those versioned 27 and earlier, and packaged as android.support.*) will remain available on Google Maven. However, all new library development will occur in the AndroidX library.

We recommend using the AndroidX libraries in all new projects. You should also consider migrating existing projects to AndroidX as well.

You shouldn't use design support library, as you are already using `androidx`. Further support library are now [deprecated and replaced with `androidx`.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library)

This library is replaced by Google material library that you already included

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'
```

Comment: thanks,but can u show me how to using Snackbar in last version

Comment: @Yαиɢ [here](https://medium.com/android-beginners/android-snackbar-example-tutorial-a40aae0fc620) you can find a full example .. If the answer was helpful thanks to mark it as accepted.